# Fill up whole table space with table cells of equal width

Tags: html, css, html-table, equals, cells

The title is pretty self explanatory, but basically I need the table row to be equal to the table space provided and for the table cells to have equal widths. I have tried numerous suggestions online but I haven't been able to figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
<div id="boxes">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h2>News</h2>

                <h6>The new website is up!</h6>
                <p>The new website is up take a look around and be sure to visit our games page and have a good time. =)</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h2>Other Stuff</h2>

                <h6>This is where some other info goes</h6>
                <p>We can type other types of information in here for the general public to know.</p>
            </td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div><!--end boxes-->
</div><!--end content-->
```

CSS:

```
#content{
text-align:center;
width:90%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;  
}
#content #boxes table{
table-layout:fixed; 
}
#content #boxes table tr td{
border-top:30px solid #000;
border-left:1px solid #000;
border-right:1px solid #000;
height:250px;
width:23%;
table-layout:fixed;
text-align:left;
float:left;
display:inline-block;   
}
#content #boxes table tr td:hover{
border-top:30px solid #F00;
border-left:1px solid #F00;
border-right:1px solid #F00;    
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand, but trying this on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KfyJ5/ it shows the table cells with an equal width..

Comment: @ErenorPaz The problem here is that the `td`s' widths add up to 92%, so the table will be sized 92%. Of #boxes, that is. See http://jsfiddle.net/UJvm5/

Comment: Uh, now it's far more clear..92% it's because of those 23% x4. The bad thing, is that width is calculated differently in various browsers. Some will include the border width, some others will not :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `#content #boxes table tr td` to:

```
border-top:30px solid #000;
border-left:1px solid #000;
border-right:1px solid #000;
border-collapse:collapse;
height:250px;
width:25%;
text-align:left;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TrDAZ/3/)

EDIT:  Thanks Pumbaa, removed unnecessary directives

Comment: Right, but `table-layout:fixed;` is not needed here. It only shows effect on tables, not on cells.